# Dynamically add optional parameters to API requests

Tags: android, retrofit

I have an Android app that communicates with a REST API.

For each request, I want my app to be able to add optional parameters in addition to the mandatory parameters.

How can I implement this with Retrofit? Currently all the parameters are hard-coded in the interface:

```
@GET("/user/{id}/comments?position={pos}")  
void getComments(@Path("id") int id, @Query("pos") int pos, Callback<String> cb);

@GET("/user/{id}/likes?n={number}")  
void getLikes(@Path("id") int id, @Query("number") int number, Callback<String> cb);

/* etc */
```

Is it possible to "sub-class" the `RestAdapter` or something to be able to dynamically add optional parameters to my requests?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have a few ways to achieve that:

- By default Retrofit handles nulls correctly for all null query parameters, so you can do something like:

  ```
  @GET("/user/{id}/likes")  
  void getLikes(@Path("id") int id, @Query("n") Integer number, @Query("pos") Integer pos Callback<String> cb);
  ```

If you use Object instead of int you can call to the method using null for the optional parameters:

```
    getLikes(1, null, null, cb); // to get /user/1/likes
    getLikes(1, 2, null, cb); // to get /user/1/likes?n=2
```

- By using RequestInterceptor:

  ```
  RestAdapter.Builder builder= new RestAdapter.Builder()
  .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
              @Override
              public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                  request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;versions=1");
                  if(/*condition*/){
                     request.addQueryParam(arg0, arg1)
                  }                      
              }
          });
  ```

Comment: Also, coming soon: Support for `Map<String, String>` as an arg for truly arbitrary query params!

Comment: You could use `Integer` instead of `Object` if you like type safety.

Comment: RequestInterceptor is simply not working for me. I made a singleton wrapper class (so I don't need to always create a new RequestInterceptor). I overrided the intercept method like this: 
@Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
        request.addHeader("X-Mashape-Key: ", MASHAPE_API_KEY);
        request.addHeader("Accept:", "application/json");
    } 
On the AdapterBuilder, I use it like this: .setRequestInterceptor(RequestHeaderInjector.getInstance()) 
and it does not do anything. I had to use Headers annotation to add the 2 headers. No error messages though :(

Answer (score 19):

Support for `Map<String,String>` is now available. Just use `@QueryMap Map<String, String> params`.

From http://square.github.io/retrofit/:

> For complex query parameter combinations a Map can be used.

Example:

```
@GET("/group/{id}/users")
List<User> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
```

Comment: `@FieldMap Map<String, String> fields;` is also available when doing `@POST` requests.